# memory is not getting freed up which was allocated before there arises an exception in constructor

Tags: c++, exception

```
 class book
   {
     int*d;
     char ch;
    public:book()
       {
          try
            {
              d=new int(23);
               throw 'A';
                ch='B';
             }
          catch(char c)
             {
                 delete d;
                cout<<"caught exception in constructor\n";
             }
       }
         void show()
             {
                cout<<*d<<endl<<ch;
              }
   };
  main()
  {
      book b;
      b.show();
  }
```

when there arises an exception in a constructor,we should free the memory allocated to avoid memory leak.But in the above code,i am trying to free the allocated memory,even then it is showing the correct answer i.e value of *d is shown as 23.why is it so?

Comment: You're invoking a UB, `d` is a dangling pointer

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Using the pointer's referent after it's been deleted, is Undefined Behavior.

It's not unnatural that the value has not been cleared or altered. But it would not be unnatural if was cleared or altered, either. And it would not be unnatural if the program crashed, whatever.

---

In other news...

Throwing a `char` or other basic value may cause trouble, or at least prevent logging of a suitable message. Ordinarily the expectation is an exception derived from `std::exception`, e.g. `std::runtime_error` or `std::system_error`.

Catching an exception in a constructor is OK in itself, but not throwing when the constructor fails is an invitation to disaster – the instantiating code will be left with an invalid object.

To facilitate cleanup in a constructor that fails, use smart pointers, standard collection classes, or custom RAII (cleanup in destructors of suitably defined types).

Declaring `main` without a result type is invalid in C++, which has never supported implicit `int`.

Regarding style, the `public:book()` looks like an access specifier applied to a single item, as in Java and C#. In C++ an access specifier starts a region with a given access. Thus it's unnatural to combine it visually with a single something.

Comment: Using the pointer after it has been deleted is UB also. [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]#4

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks. But formally-pedantic, "the pointer" is also a bit too vague: it's using the pointer *value*, after it's become invalid, that's UB. This includes copying it or comparing it. In contrast, in the case of a pointer variable, such as in the OP's code, the variable can be freely used, in particular it can be reused or nulled.

Comment: Hoist by my own petard